# Using a public ECR image in local Kubernetes cluster in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-ecr

I've setup a very **simple local kubernetes cluster** for development purposes, and for that I aim to pull a docker image for my pods from ECR.

Here's the code

```
   terraform {
      required_providers {
        kubernetes = {
          source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
          version = ">= 2.0.0"
        }
      }
    }

    provider "kubernetes" {
        config_path = "~/.kube/config"
    } 

    resource "kubernetes_deployment" "test" {
      metadata {
        name      = "test-deployment"
        namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
      }

      spec {
        replicas = 2
        selector {
          match_labels = {
            app = "MyTestApp"
          }
        }

        template {
          metadata {
            labels = {
              app = "MyTestApp"
            }
          }

          spec {
            container {
              image = "public ECR URL"  <--- this times out
              name  = "myTestPod"
    
              port {
                container_port = 4000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I've set that **ECR repo to public** and made sure that **it's accessible**. My challenge is that in a normal scenario **you have to login to ECR** in order to retrieve the image, and I do not know **how to achieve that in Terraform**. So on 'terraform apply', it times out and fails.

I read the documentation on [aws_ecr_repository](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecr_repository), [aws_ecr_authorization_token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ecr_authorization_token),[Terraform EKS module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest) and [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec), but none of them seem to have a solution for this.

Achieving this in a Gitlab pipeline is fairly easy, but how can one achieve this in Terraform? how can I pull an image from a public **ECR repo for my local Kubernetes** cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, I figured out the cleanest way to achieve this;

**First** retrieve your **ECR authorization token** data;

```
data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {
}
```

**Second**, create a **secret for your kubernetes** cluster**:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "docker" {
  metadata {
    name      = "docker-cfg"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
  }

  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = jsonencode({
      auths = {
        "${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint}" = {
          auth = "${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.authorization_token}"
        }
      }
    })
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
}
```

Bear in mind that the example in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret) base64 encodes the username and password. The exported attribute **authorization_token** does the same thing.

**Third**, once the secret is created, you can then have your pods use it as the **image_pull_secrets**:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "test" {
  metadata {
    name      = "MyTestApp"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
  }
  spec {
    replicas = 2

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "MyTestApp"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "MyTestApp"
        }
      }


      spec {

        image_pull_secrets {
          name = "docker-cfg"
        }

        container {
          image             = "test-image-URL"
          name              = "test-image-name"
          image_pull_policy = "Always"


          port {
            container_port = 4000
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
      kubernetes_secret.docker,
  ]
}
```

**Gotcha**: the token **expires after 12 hours**, so you should either write a bash script that updates your secret in the corresponding namespace, or you should write a [Terraform provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax) that gets triggered every time the token expires.

I hope this was helpful.